# mysqli conversion PDO

Tags: php, pdo

How can I turn this to PDO? I tried, but I don't know how.
It was `MySQLi` at first and I tried to turn it to `PDO` and so, that was the result:

```
<?php
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $stmt = $conn-> prepare("SELECT * FROM resident WHERE '$username' = ? AND '$password' = ?");
    //mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sql, "ss", $username, $password);
    $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
    $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password);
    $stmt ->execute();
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($sql);
    $stmt-> BindParam($sql, $name, $username, $password);
    $response=array();
    $response["succes"] = false;
    while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($sql)) {
        $response["success"] = true;
        $response["name"]= $name;
    }
    echo json_encode ($response);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing variables with column names. It's extremely important to note the difference. In a query `'$username'` is a *string* with a value in it, and probably a [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). `username` without quotes is probably a column name.

You're also using named placeholders but you haven't named them. `?` is an unnamed one. If you want a placeholder named `:x` then `:x` must appear in the query.

Your fixed code should look like:

```
$stmt = $conn-> prepare("SELECT * FROM resident WHERE username=:username AND password=:password");
//mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sql, "ss", $username, $password);

$stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
$stmt->bindParam(':password', $password);
$stmt ->execute();
```

That is technically functional but **VERY, VERY WRONG**. Passwords **must** be properly hashed using, at the absolute least, [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php). If you do that you can no longer fetch based on username and password, you need to fetch based on username and use [`password_verify`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to check if it's correct or not.

## Disclaimer: Don't Write Your Own Login System

Unless this is strictly for academic purposes, all of this code is pretty much a waste of time. Any [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) has a solution for this. One example is [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) where out of the box you get a full-featured [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication).

Comment: is there another problems in the codes buddy?? just clarification. :)

Comment: @Lie Yes. Many.

Answer (score 1):

You can use answer of tadman, also this:

```
$stmt = $conn-> prepare("SELECT `id` FROM resident WHERE username=:username AND password=:password");

$stmt->execute(array(':username' => $username, ':password' => $password);
```

And hash your passwords.
You can learn some basics of pdo [Here, W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp)